# Fancy Box is not working with Box slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I am doing a project for one of my client. I am using box slider for the banner and it works fine. For a specific page on the website I am also trying to use fancy box for image light box.But It doesn't work however box slider is still working. Here is the head tag.

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#single_2").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'float'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }
</style>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the the element where I am trying to use fancy box

```
<a href="images/lightbox/groups-size-option.jpg" target="_blank" id="single_2" title="Work Shops Chart">
    <img src="images/group-size.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
</a>
```

when I disable box slider fancy box works. But when it is active fancy box doesn't work. Please help asap.Thanks

Comment: Why are you including jQuery in the page three times?

Comment: Why are you including boxes in the page twice?